# Symfony2.1: extra field in login form to be persisted

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a login form in Symfony2.1, which is posted to my route, which has no controller attached, as Symfony takes care of the login internally.

Now how would I add a field to this form, call a SetXxxx() method on an entity, and persist it? I have no way of intercepting the POST value of my login form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing a custom [Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) and creating your own authentication [Token](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.php) which persists one of it's members.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a lot of trouble creating an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` ( see http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/set-up-authenticationsuccesshandler.html ), and injecting the entity manager or whatever service you have that takes care of updating your entity and persist it.

That blog implements directly the interface `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`, but you can do it as well extending `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and making your additions in `onAuthenticationSuccess`